# A question about totally disconnected point sets.

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let H be an infinite dimensional and separable Hilbert space. Let C be a closed and
connected subset of H containing more than one point. Can C ever be the countable union
of closed and totally disconnected subsets of H?

Answer (score 2):

Let $E_c$ be the *complete Erdös space* (Erdös, Annals of Math vol 41 1940), defined as the subspace of $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ where all coordinates are irrationals. It is [polish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space) (separable and completely metrizable) and totally disconnected, but admits a "connectification"  namely a (still polish) topology on $E_c\cup\{p\}$ that makes it connected (and of course induces the one on $E_c$). The crucial point is the fact that any nonempty closed and open subset of $E_c$ is unbounded. Then, as in Bill Johnson's answer  $E_c$ is the union of the closed and totally disconnected subspaces $\overline{B}(0,n)\cup\{p\}$, $n\geq 1$. It remains to remark that, like any polish space, $E_c\cup\{p\}$ embeds as a closed subset of $H$ (as remarked in Gerald Edgar's answer).

Answer (score 0):

$C$ is simply a connected complete separable metric space with more than one point.
Now the union of countably many closed sets of topological dimension zero must again have dimension zero.  But I suppose "totally disconnected" is not quite the same as "zero dimensional" so this is not yet a complete answer.

Comment: These are the same thing if the set is compact. There exist separable, metrizable, totally disconnected spaces of all dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Let $C$ be an explosion point space such as the Knaster–Kuratowski fan (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster–Kuratowski_fan) and $p$ the explosion point in $C$.
Set $A_n = \{p\}\cup  (C\sim B(p; 1/n))$.

Comment: Now the K-K fan is not complete (not a $G_\delta$  set in $\mathbb{R}^2$), right? So it cannot be embedded as a closed subset of Hilbert space.

Comment: Oops! I missed that condition. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for that example based on the complete Erdos space which
answers my question in the affirmative. But I would like to clarify
a couple of points. If E is the complete Erdos space and F is the
connected metric space in which E is embedded, is F obtained by
adjoining a single point p to E? If so, how is F metrized? In other
words, how are the distances from p to the other points of F defined?

Comment: Yes, $F$ is $E$ with one point added. But exhibiting a complete metric on $F$ is not obvious. At least a metric defining the "right" (connected) topology is implicit in the proof of theorem 1 in this reference : 
http://www.few.vu.nl/~dijkstra/research/papers/2007connectible.pdf

Comment: More precisely, it embeds $F$ as a (connected) $G_\delta$ set $X$ in the Hilbert cube $Q=[0,1]^\mathbb{N}$. Then the closure $Y=\overline{X}$ has the property that $Y\setminus X=\bigcup_n F_n$, an increasing union of closed subsets of $Y$ (hence of $Q$). Then, if $d$ is a compatible metric on $Q$, a complete compatible metric on $X\simeq F$ is obtained by embedding it as a closed subset of $P=Q\times]0,\infty[^\mathbb{N}$, via $x\mapsto (x,(1/d(x,F_n))_n)$, and defining a complete compatible metric on $P$ (which is easy).
PS: I am not Bill Johnson.